# quickest way to update Linq to SQL dbml with VS 2015

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

In the latest versions of visual studio is there finally an alternative to deleting and creating again a table on a dbml file to reflect simple changes such as adding a columnn in the database ?

A thirdparty tool can be useful only if it's more efficient that dropping and recreating the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, that Linq2SQL is developed anymore.
Neither are VS tools for it.
I am not aware of any 3rd party L2S tools existing.

Comment: not very helpful. Linq2Sql is mature and doesn't need active development.